# How to make custom block in TinyMce and make it draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I've encountered a strange problem, maybe you can assist me.

I'm using TinyMce wysiwyg editor. Recently I decided to create a draggable 
block element inside editors text 
(not in the editor UI itself, but inside editable text).

New element is a div with custom class, all works well, except two things.

First - I can`t "select" this new element with 'click' action. When I try to select this block, editor selects only text inside it. 
I need to select this element as a whole object so I could dragit and copy/paste it, like images or media elements from standard plug-ins.

Second - for some reason I cant init draggable/sortable JQuery plugin inside editor text. This feature would be very helpful, but I cant find any reference to it in TinyMCE documentation. I've tried using .draggable() from jquery-ui, but div is simply dissapearing after drag ends.

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/Rutori/pen/eRxEox

div looks like this:

```
<div class="cooldiv" data-name="Drag me!"></div>
```

Please assist.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

So, basically you just needed to set property «contenteditable="false"»